# to find if a value already exists within a partition (SQL)

Tags: postgresql

so i have this below data:

```
term    period  id
7       201910  A2C5
7       201911  A2C5
7       201912  A2C5
7       202001  A2C5
7       202002  A2C5
7       202003  A2C5
7       202004  A2C5
```

i have to find the % of new id's per term per period. so basically in the above table as id A2C5 first appears first in period 201910 in term 7, that row should show 100%. And rest of the other rows should show 0% as that id is already present before.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit complicated, but it should get you where you need to go. It starts by finding the earliest term and period for each of the IDs, then divides the count of new IDs in the term&period by the count of all IDs in that same term&period.

```sql
-- Find the earliest instance of each ID
WITH earliest_instances AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * 
    FROM your_table
    ORDER BY id, term, period  -- you may need to adjust this order
), 
-- For each term and period, count how many IDs showed up there first
earliest_counts AS (
    SELECT term, period, count(*) 
    FROM earliest_instances 
    GROUP BY term, period
), 
-- For each term and period, count how many IDs there are in total
total_counts AS (
    SELECT term, period, count(*) 
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY term, period
)
-- Put those together to make a percentage of new IDs
SELECT 
    total_counts.term,
    total_counts.period, 
    100 * COALESCE(earliest_counts.count, 0) / total_counts.count AS new_ids_percentage 
FROM total_counts 
LEFT JOIN earliest_counts ON (
    total_counts.term = earliest_counts.term 
    AND total_counts.period = earliest_counts.period
)
ORDER BY term, period;

 term | period | new_ids_percentage
------+--------+--------------------
 7    | 201910 |                100
 7    | 201911 |                  0
 7    | 201912 |                  0
 7    | 202001 |                  0
 7    | 202002 |                  0
 7    | 202003 |                  0
 7    | 202004 |                  0
(7 rows)
```